# How do I get the percentage value next to row in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have following query which returns `top 50 SUM(DetailTins)` records. I need to have another column which show the percentage of `SUM(DetailTins)` over all records in the table not only first 50.

What do I need to modify in following query?

Also I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 so I cannot use `Over partition by` function.

```
WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT        
        ID, Name, City, State, SUM(DetailTins) AS SumTins
    FROM            
        FeedRpts
    WHERE 
        (RptTimeFrame BETWEEN @BeginDate AND @EndDate) 
        AND ((@VALUE = 'TN' AND STATE = 'TN') 
             OR (@VALUE = 'OOS' AND STATE <> 'TN') 
             OR (@VALUE = 'ALL'))
    GROUP BY 
        ID, Name, City, State
)
SELECT TOP 50 * 
FROM CTE 
ORDER BY SumTins DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

You can introduce another variable to calculate total sum, and then use this variable to calculate percentage:

```
DECLARE @TotalTins INT

SELECT @TotalTins = SUM(DetailTins) FROM FeedRpts
WHERE (RptTimeFrame BETWEEN @BeginDate AND @EndDate) AND ((@VALUE = 'TN' AND STATE = 'TN') OR  (@VALUE = 'OOS' AND STATE <> 'TN') OR (@VALUE = 'ALL'))

WITH CTE
AS 
(
SELECT        ID, Name, City, State, SUM(DetailTins) AS SumTins
FROM            FeedRpts
WHERE (RptTimeFrame BETWEEN @BeginDate AND @EndDate) AND ((@VALUE = 'TN' AND STATE = 'TN') OR  (@VALUE = 'OOS' AND STATE <> 'TN') OR (@VALUE = 'ALL'))
GROUP BY ID, Name, City, State
)
SELECT TOP 50 *, CAST(SumTins AS float) / CAST(@TotalTins AS float)  AS Percentage   
FROM CTE ORDER BY SumTins DESC
```

Comment: Good point -- my answer didn't incorporate the actual creation of the percentage value. The OP needs to divide that and more than likely CAST the denominator as a FLOAT, or he'll just end up with a lot of 0 and 1s instead of fractions.

Comment: @Boyd-P Thanks for your comment - you are 100% right. I have updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @ssum int = (select SUM(DetailTins) AS SumTins from FeedRpts);
WITH CTE
AS 
(
SELECT ID, Name, City, State, SUM(DetailTins) AS SumTins
FROM   FeedRpts
WHERE (RptTimeFrame BETWEEN @BeginDate AND @EndDate) 
AND   (   (@VALUE = 'TN'  AND STATE =  'TN') 
       OR (@VALUE = 'OOS' AND STATE <> 'TN') 
       OR (@VALUE = 'ALL')
      )
GROUP BY ID, Name, City, State
)
SELECT TOP (50) *, @ssum as ssum, 100.0 * SumTins / @ssum as [pct] 
FROM CTE 
ORDER BY SumTins DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a nested subquery in your SELECT statement. I don't think you even need the CTE in this, but since you've already written it, I'll just add the subquery.

```
WITH CTE
AS 
(
SELECT        ID, Name, City, State, SUM(DetailTins) AS SumTins
FROM            FeedRpts
WHERE (RptTimeFrame BETWEEN @BeginDate AND @EndDate) AND ((@VALUE = 'TN' AND STATE = 'TN') OR  (@VALUE = 'OOS' AND STATE <> 'TN') OR (@VALUE = 'ALL'))
GROUP BY ID, Name, City, State
)
SELECT TOP 50 *, (SELECT SumTins FROM CTE) AS AllRecordSumTins FROM CTE ORDER BY SumTins DESC
```

You may need to SUM that within the subquery: (SELECT Sum(SumTins) FROM CTE) AS AllRecordSumTins

Answer (score 0):

See my changes of your query below:

```
SELECT     
    ID, Name, City, State, 
    SUM(DetailTins) AS SumTins, 
    SUM(DetailTins) / (SELECT SUM(DetailTins) FROM FeedRpts) * 100 AS Percent_of_Total
FROM
    FeedRpts
WHERE 
    (RptTimeFrame BETWEEN @BeginDate AND @EndDate) 
    AND ((@VALUE = 'TN' AND STATE = 'TN') OR  
         (@VALUE = 'OOS' AND STATE <> 'TN') OR (@VALUE = 'ALL'))
GROUP BY 
    ID, Name, City, State
```